# Extraer nombres de Array String e ir vaciando en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un Array de String con varios nombres, que salgan aleatoriamente y cuando salga un nombre que desaparezca de la lista. Las dos condiciones son que cuando el Array se vacíe el programa termine o cuando el usuario escriba salir. Solo me falta que el nombre que salga se vaya borrando del Array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] lista = {"Antonio", "Juan", "Manuel", "Victor"};

    boolean salir = false;
    String teclado = "";
    do {

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

            if (teclado.equalsIgnoreCase("salir")) {
                salir = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Pulse intro para sortear otro nombre"
                        + "(para cerrar escriba salir): ");
                teclado = S.nextLine();
                int a = (int) (Math.random() * lista.length);
                System.out.println(lista[a]+"\n");
            }

        }

    } while (!salir);

}
```

Comment: Los arrays son de longitud fija, no puedes cambiar su tamaño una vez creados, algo que sí puedes hacer con `ArrayList` por ejemplo. En este caso, dado que `lista` es un array fijo, lo único que puedes hacer es setear su valor a `null`, pero no removerlo, con algo así: `lista[a] = null;` pero esto crea un problema añadido y es que tendrás que verificar que el random no se vuelve a repetir para un valor ya seteado a `null`.

Comment: Si necesitas tener un arreglo fijo, lo que puedes hacer, es dar un valor nulo a los que vayas eliminando y pasar estos valores hasta el último index del arreglo, los demás índices que si tienen valores, los deberás de recorrer un espacio. Además necesitarás tener una variable que indique la cantidad de elementos que tienes en el arreglo y así en vez de iterar de 0 hasta el Length, iterarás hasta el total de elementos. Esta variable que simula el total de elementos, deberá de ser cambiada cada que elimines un elemento. Por otro lado, si no tienes restricción en el tipo de instrucciones a usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien te han comentado A.Cedano....

Los Arrays en java no se les puede eliminar posiciones....

Lo único que puedes hacer es, o bien le asignas a la posición del array donde rescatas el dato un valor null, por ejemplo asi

```
lista[i]=null;
```

o bien,le asignas una cadena de texto vacia de esta forma:

```
lista[i]="";
```

otra cosa que se me olvidaba, es que en este codigo

```
     int a = (int) (Math.random() * lista.length);
```

Deberas crear un bucle While que se repita mientras la posición del array que analizas tiene un dato guardado a nulo o tiene una cadena de texto vacia